# Understanding syntax of the statement "rescue ErrorType1, ErrorType2 => ex"

Tags: ruby

A quick query: 
How would a Java programmer will understand the following Ruby statement:

```
rescue ErrorType1, ErrorType2 => ex
```

That is, I want to put brackets/parenthesis around it explicitly. 
So, is it?

```
rescue(ErrorType1, {ErrorType2 => ex})
```

or,

```
rescue({[ErrorType1, ErrorType2] => ex})
```

or, something else...

Comment: what you are trying to do ? Why the curly braces `{}` ?

Comment: @Arup it appears to me that we are using poetry form here and so leaving away brackets and parenthesis.. I just want to understand what kind of argument it is?

Comment: @Munish it's not poetry in this case, see my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the syntax:

```
rescue ErrorType1, ErrorType2 => ex
```

Please note following:

1. There is no hash involved
2. 'rescue' is not a method, you can't even write it as rescue(ErrorType1, ErrorType2 => ex)
3. Ruby places a reference to raised associated exception into the
   global variable $!.
4. In the above form, the 'rescue' takes a **special argument** where
   you give the name of a local variable to receive the matched
   exception, which is more readable then using $!.

Now, look at the syntax again...

Answer (score 2):

`rescue` is a control structure with it's own syntax, it's not a method call, so your 2nd and 3rd code blocks are invalid syntax, you aren't not passing any arguments.

`rescue <exception-class1>[, <exception-class2>] => <a variable to assign the exception to>`

so when doing `rescue TypeError, StandardError => my_exception` it will catch any `TypeError` or `StandardError` exception that is raised and assign it to the `my_exception` local variable.

I suggest the recently translated [Ruby Hacking Guide](http://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/spec.html) (search for "rescue").

Answer (score 1):

Look at the below code :

```
begin
    a=1/0
rescue => e
    p e.class
    p defined?(e)
end
# >> ZeroDivisionError
# >> "local-variable"
```

Where `e` is a local variable to that exception handling block. In Ruby local variables are created using assignment operation,but in case of exception handling,reference to the currently raised exception is assigned to the local variable e using the hash rocket(`=>`),instead of `=`. This is as per design. Don't think of that it is a **Hash**.

In Ruby we use one or more rescue clauses to tell Ruby the types of exceptions we want to handle.If you write a rescue clause with no parameter list, the parameter defaults to `StandardError`. Each rescue clause can specify multiple exceptions to catch. At the end of each rescue clause you can give Ruby the name of a local variable to receive the matched exception. The parameters to the rescue clause can also be arbitrary expressions (including method calls) that return an Exception class. If we use raise with no parameters, it re-raises the exception.[**Handling an Exception**](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html)

Out of three of your codes only valid is `rescue ErrorType1, ErrorType2 => ex`. Others will give you syntax error.

***Hierarchy(partial) :***

```
StandardError
   |
  IndexError
      |
     KeyError
```

You can specify the error class names as arguments to the `rescue` list,in any order.On runtime ruby will pick up the correct one from the list. Look the code below :

```
begin
    a = {}
    a.fetch(:b)
rescue StandardError,KeyError,IndexError => e
    p e.class
end
# >> KeyError

begin
    a = {}
    a.fetch(:b)
rescue KeyError,StandardError,IndexError => e
    p e.class
end
# >> KeyError
```

If you think,you would tell Ruby interpreter on runtime, which one to match first using *paren* from the argument list,Ruby ***will not allow*** you to do so,in return it will throw to you syntax error. Same also for below :

```
begin
    a = {}
    a.fetch(:b)
rescue StandardError => e1
    p e1.class
rescue IndexError => e2
    p e2.class
rescue KeyError => e3
    p e3.class
end
# >> KeyError
```

Note: If we want to catch more exception classes, we can just write them in line. When we want to handle different errors differently, we can specify several `rescue` clauses.[**Ruby Hacking Guide**](http://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/spec.html)

Comment: Thanks Arup for these details, but I was just confused with the syntax.